# Rx Java 2 Sync vs. Async

Tags: rx-java2

I know type of synch vs. async where Observable can be processed on main thread or on background thread specified by subscribeOn (potentially observeOn). This case is clear.

Can you explain me where is a different between synchrounous and asychronous operator? Asynchronous operator can change order of items from upstream?

Which operators are asynchronous? Only merge and flatMap?

When all operators in chain are synchronous that emitted item must be processed using entire chain before next item can be processed? Chain with map and filter.

Answer (score 0):

Any operator that has to deal with multiple sources or takes a Scheduler is considered an asynchronous boundary - async for short.

Multi-source operators may encounter signals from multiple threads; even if there was a total order of these signals, some operators, such as `merge()` may not emit them in the same order. Generally though, signals from a source may end up interleaved with signals from other sources.

Synchronous chains go in deep into the chain of `onNext` calls and unless there are some buffering happening, they have to return up to the top-source for the next element.